# How to store and use functions in a data.table?

Tags: r, function, data.table

What is the correct way to store a series of functions in a data.table and then efficiently use each function to produce some result?

```
# create data
dt <- data.table(name = c('a', 'b', 'c'), 
                 value1 = c(25, 35, 45), 
                 value2 = c(50, 60, 70), 
                 units1 = c(100, 200, 300), 
                 units2 = c(300, 400, 500))

# function to create row-specific functions:
get_spline_fun <- function(data){
  splinefunH(
    x = c(0, data[['value1']]/data[['value2']], 5),
    y = c(0, data['units1']/data['units2'], 1),
    m = c(1.2, 1, 0))
}

# create functions and store in a new column
dt$spline_fun <- apply(
  dt[, c('value1', 'value2', 'units1', 'units2')], 1, get_spline_fun)

# create x values
x <- seq(0, 5, 0.01)

# apply functions to x values
dt[, y := spline_fun(x)]
# Results in: Error in spline_fun(x) : could not find function "spline_fun"
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem that you are going to have is that the function you are creating returns 501 values; that will not fit into the "y" column you are trying to create because the data.table only has 3 rows.

The other issue is that if you look at the structure of the data.table the spline_fun is a list and you would have to reference it something like:

```
dt[, y := spline_fun[[.N]](x)]
```

so that you are applying the .Nth function in the list.  You are going to have to have another object that is going to hold the 3 columns of 501 rows of data, so you might have to rethink the problem.  You can also store it in a list as:

```
dt[, y := list(spline_fun[[.N]](x))]
```

but I am not sure how you invoke the proper function since in the statement above it is always going to call the 3rd function since .N = 3.

You might want a "for" loop to create the "list" values by call the appropriate function and then store the list back into "dt".